# Как исправить System.Net.Sockets.SocketException?

Tags: c#, wpf

как устранить System.Net.Sockets.SocketException?

```
    private void Send(string from,string to,string subject,string body,string password)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mailMessage.To.Add(to);
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.Body = body;
        SmtpClient newClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
        newClient.EnableSsl = true;
        newClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);
        try
        {
            newClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (SmtpException exception)
        {
            StreamWriter exceptionWriter = new StreamWriter("exc.txt");
            exceptionWriter.Write(exception.ToString());
            exceptionWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

значения переменных совпадают с ожидаемыми.вот содержимое exc.txt:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной
>   почты. ---> System.Net.WebException: Невозможно соединиться с
>   удаленным сервером ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Попытка
>   установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за
>   требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже
>   установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного
>   компьютера 217.69.139.200:25    в
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> в System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)    --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека
>   исключений ---
>
> в System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6)
>
> в System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean
>   async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>
> в System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>
> в System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
>
> в System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)
>
> в System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)
>
> в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>
> в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>
> --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
>
> в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>
> в MailSending.MainWindow.Send(String from, String to, String
>   subject, String body, String password) в
>   d:\Users\dave\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\MailSending\MailSending\MainWindow.xaml.cs:строка 61

Comment: Ну, может, сервер и правда не ответил. Например, если вы слишком часто ему шлёте запросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP у mail.ru (и у многих других) использует SSL/TLS и порт, отличный от 25-го. У [mail.ru это 465](https://help.mail.ru/enmail-help/mailer/popsmtp):

```
newClient.Port = 465;
```